# How do I fix this miscode with my Console RPG SHA-256 game save protection?

Tags: c++, console, sha256

So I'm making a console rpg and after the task of making my save/load functions (Works perfectly) I began making a sha-256 checksum so the save file can't be edited. I've pretty much all of the code but when I save the game and the checksum of that save file with my save function, I go back to load it and it always goes to the statement that says the checksums do not match and when I check the chksum.dat the hash is the same every time, I'm truly stumped on this, here is my code:

(There is more code but it's irrelevant, I think)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "sha256.h"
using namespace std;


string userinput = "nul";
string name = "nul";
string currentenchant = "nul";
string checksum1 = "nul";
string checksum2 = "nul";
string checksum3 = "nul";
int namelength=0;
int magnumb=0;
int stonenumb=5;
int glowingstone=0;
int redgem=0;
int raind=0;
int trainswordatk=10;
int trainswordspd=10;
int trainswordlevel=0;
int swordmagicdmg=15;
int equippedmagic=0;
int equippedmagicmax=1;
int savelength=0;
bool trainsword=false;
bool firetrainsword=false;
bool icetrainsword=false;
bool poisontrainsword=false;
bool beginchest=false;
bool swordmagic=false;
bool swordmagicequip=false;

 void SaveGame()
{
  ofstream data("data.dat");
  data << "\n";
  data <<name;
  data << "\n";
  data <<userinput;
  data << "\n";
  data <<currentenchant;
  data << "\n";
  data <<magnumb;
  data << "\n";
  data <<stonenumb;
  data << "\n";
  data <<glowingstone;
  data << "\n";
  data <<redgem;
  data << "\n";
  data <<raind;
  data << "\n";
  data <<trainswordatk;
  data << "\n";
  data <<trainswordspd;
  data << "\n";
  data <<trainswordlevel;
  data << "\n";
  data <<trainsword;
  data << "\n";
  data <<firetrainsword;
  data << "\n";
  data <<icetrainsword;
  data << "\n";
  data <<poisontrainsword;
  data << "\n";
  data <<beginchest;
  data << "\n";
  data <<swordmagic;
  data << "\n";
  data <<swordmagicdmg;
  data << "\n";
  data <<swordmagicequip;
  data << "\n";
  data <<equippedmagicmax;
  data << "\n";
  data <<equippedmagic;
  data << "\n";
  data <<namelength;
  data << "\n";
  ofstream data1("data.dat");
  ofstream chksum("chksum.dat");
  checksum1 = sha256("data.dat");
  chksum << checksum1;
}

void LoadGame()
{
int add = 0;
string line;
ifstream chksum("chksum.dat");
getline(chksum, line) >> checksum2;
ifstream chcsum("data.dat");
checksum3 = sha256("data.dat");
if (checksum3==checksum2)
{
  goto goodcheck;
 } else if (checksum3!=checksum2) {
    cout << "Your current save has been modified     from your previous one.\n\n";
    cout << "Current: " << checksum3 <<    "\nPrevious: " << checksum2 << "\n\n";
    getch();
    exit(0);
   } else {
cout << "There has been an error loading your game, please try again.\n\n";
getch();
return;
}

goodcheck:
ifstream data("data.dat");
while(data.is_open()){
    if (add==0) getline(data, line) >> name;
    if (add==1) getline(data, line) >> userinput;
    if (add==2) getline(data, line) >> currentenchant;
    if (add==3) getline(data, line) >> magnumb;
    if (add==4) getline(data, line) >> stonenumb;
    if (add==5) getline(data, line) >> glowingstone;
    if (add==6) getline(data, line) >> redgem;
    if (add==7) getline(data, line) >> raind;
    if (add==8) getline(data, line) >> trainswordatk;
    if (add==9) getline(data, line) >> trainswordspd;
    if (add==10) getline(data, line) >> trainswordlevel;
    if (add==11) getline(data, line) >> trainsword;
    if (add==12) getline(data, line) >> firetrainsword;
    if (add==13) getline(data, line) >> icetrainsword;
    if (add==14) getline(data, line) >> poisontrainsword;
    if (add==15) getline(data, line) >> beginchest;
    if (add==16) getline(data, line) >> swordmagic;
    if (add==17) getline(data, line) >> swordmagicdmg;
    if (add==18) getline(data, line) >> swordmagicequip;
    if (add==19) getline(data, line) >> equippedmagicmax;
    if (add==20) getline(data, line) >> equippedmagic;
    if (add==21) getline(data, line) >> namelength;
    if (add==22) getline(data, line) >> savelength;
    //if (add==23) getline(data, line) >> ; (These are for future use convenience)
    //if (add==24) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==25) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==26) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==27) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==28) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==29) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==30) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==31) getline(data, line) >> ;
    //if (add==32) getline(data, line) >> ;
    if (add==22) data.close();
    add++;
  }
  cout << "Game loaded.\n";
  getch();
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions that resemble _"somebody debug this"_ don't often get a positive response.  Have you tried running this in a debugger?

Comment: I have debugged, the program ran, and I experienced the same problem

Comment: As a side note: The coding style is really bad! Why on earth all those global variable definitions, and encouraged copy/paste programming?!?

Comment: I don't see the style as an issue, really. I code to get the job done, that's worked to fit the needs of my programs

Comment: @user3788769 _'I have debugged, the program ran, and I experienced the same problem'_ Well, what else would you expect? Running in a debugger doesn't _magically_ fix the problem, but helps you to find it by stepping through line by line and watch how variable values change.

Comment: Yes, I could not find the problem

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
getline(chksum, line) >> checksum2;
```

reads a line from the file into `line` and then reads another string into `checksum2`. This doesn't match how you write to the checksum file.

Step through in a debugger until you get to that line and you will find that `line` contains the checksum and `checksum2` is empty.

Change it to

```
getline(chksum, checksum2);
```

Note: You really should make some of your variables into local variables and name them appropriately. It may be easy for you to follow your program now, but in 6 months time you will find it a lot harder, when it isn't fresh in your mind.

Comment: Thanks for that and the note, I don't have access to my computer right now but when I do I'll do that.